# Dashboard is not running as another user user for Salesforce platform User

Tags: dashboard

I've created dashboard which is to be run as system admin User "ABC".

I've provided a folder permission to another user "`X`" which is above in role hierarchy and its Salesforce Licence is "`Salesfroce Platform`".

Now I want this user should be able to view the Dashboard Run as "ABC". But When i open the Dashboard I can see `Insufficient Privileged access`.

I've read online, Salesforce platform user can not able to view the dashboard which is viewing as another user with different licence.

Still I want to show for USEr `X` to view dashboard run as another user.

How can be it possible without changing the licence of User `X`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add permission **"View My Team's Dashboards"** in User X profile.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dashboards_dynamic_setting_up.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000biHgAAI

Sorry, can't do it with standard Dashboards. I have even found that, for dynamic Dashboards meant to run as the current user, if the **owner** of the dashboard has a full Salesforce licence, I get errors. I end up having to reassign the ownership to a Platform licence user.

Ultimately it breaks your licence agreement to attempt to surface data from CRM objects that a Platform licence should not be allowed to see. However if it's just a question of data that the licence type can see but not the user profile, set up an "all access" Platform user who can see more of the data, and run the dashboard as that user.